# Table View Cell tap Crashed

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

I have added a ViewController as a subview to UIWindow & added a tableView inside view Controller but while i am tapping on cell app crashes in device & cells disappear in simulator Strange Issue!!!

[image: this is the error]

```
    class func addSideMenu(viewControllerName : String)->UIView{
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: MAIN_STORYBOARD, bundle: nil)
    let vc = (storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(viewControllerName))
    vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(-(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width + 100),0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 100, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height)
    print(vc.view.frame)
    vc.view.tag = 200
    return vc.view
}


 newView = Utilities.addSideMenu("SideMenuViewController")
```

`UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window!!.addSubview(newView!)`

Comment: What's the message in the debug console?

Comment: Can't help you without seeing your code, the console error etc. Edit your question and add these details

Comment: no errors in console only i am getting a main thread error

Comment: @samad5353 google how to set a breakpoint on an exception throw, to see the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bad idea to create a view controller, take its view, and then let the controller drop out of scope.  If you do that, any dependencies inside the view -- such as table view delegate functions, for example -- are likely to crash.

You should either hold on to the controller for as long as you use its view or, if you must dispose of the controller, make sure it has no connections to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Your view controllers should be a subclass of `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController`, less you bypass the inherited dependencies and cause unwanted behavior.

Also, your view controller should have `tableView.delegate = self` and `tableView.dataSource = self` in your initializer or `viewDidLoad()` That might be part of the issue for your case.